# Open source version of Community Translation Submission System

Tags: open-source, translation

I would like to have the community provide translations for some of my application in an easier way. Looking around I found about openCTI. Any open source equivalent of [openCTI](https://translate.sun.com/opencti/)?

Edit: Looks like openCTI was just decommissioned. Still the need for such software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a dumb question. After a while I found the Kenai project itself: http://kenai.com/projects/cti